# How can I send the results from a form :remote => true in Rails 3 back to the page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms

This is part of my controller:

```
if @invite.save
      UserMailer.invite_email(@invite).deliver
      respond_with do |format|
        format.html do
          if request.xhr?
            render :text => "sent" , :layout => false
          else
            flash[:notice] = "Successfully created invite."
            redirect_to @invite
          end
        end
      end
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
```

This is my View:

```
<h3>Invite a Friend</h3>
<%= form_for @invite, :remote => true do |f| %>
  <%= f.email_field :recipient_email, :class => 'submittable' %></br>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

What do I need to do so that, for example, the text "sent" or anything I put there appears right above the form on the View?

I tried `:update => :status` but that didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that you have to send back javascript that gets executed instead of just sending back text like "sent". Using your example (and assuming you're using jQuery):

```
if request.xhr?
  render :text => "$('#invite_form').before('<div>Sent!</div>');" , :layout => false
else
  ...
end
```

(Be sure the form has an `id` and use that instead of `#invite_form`.)

Since you're using `remote: true` on the form it should automatically execute the response. In general though, I think you'd be better served by cleaning up your response logic a little bit and separating the xhr response into its own template. Check out this page under the **"Using responds_with"** section for some great examples:
http://asciicasts.com/episodes/224-controllers-in-rails-3

Comment: @mirthlab -- I see....I found it alot easier with Rails 2 using :update .... I thought Rails used prototype, should I use the jquery gem to substitute?

Comment: There's nothing wrong using Prototype, it's just the `:text => "..."` line would have to use prototype syntax instead. Rails 3.1 will ship with jQuery by default though (as noted by [DHH on Twitter](https://twitter.com/#!/dhh/status/45923430608023552)) so it might be worth getting acquainted with it.

Comment: @mirthlab -- I see, so before, we didn't have to write any javascript, right, but now we learn jquery to use javascript instead of using rails?  thanks...

Comment: @mirthlab -- which approach, there is also an approach os using create.js.erb what is the difference or benefits?

Comment: @mirthlab, I see, if I use responds_with and I put it into a create.js.erb, would that do it?

Comment: Exactly. That's "the better way" to do it since it'll clean up your controllers a bit and keep your view logic separate.